# Remove upload button of FileUpload.GetHtml Helper

Tags: html, razor, helper, webmatrix

How can I remove the upload button helper FileUpload.GetHtml?

```
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,
        includeFormTag:true,
        addText:"Adicionar",
        uploadText:"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The only way to remove it using code is to set `includeFormTag` to `false`. But then you'd lose all the rest of the post html. :)

However, since the html output is consistent you can just do a simple replace.

```
@Html.Raw(FileUpload.GetHtml(
    initialNumberOfFiles:1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,
    includeFormTag:true,
    addText:"Adicionar",
    uploadText:"").ToString().Replace("<input value=\"\" type=\"submit\"/>", ""))
```

It's rather ugly though.

Comment: Thanks .. also resolves.

But I decided via CSS  
.file-upload-buttons input[value="Upload"]
{
    display:none;
}